# How to show my brand on whoishostingthis.com?

Tags: web-hosting

You guys must have heard about whoishostingthis.com. If you type any URL it will let you know whose the hosting provided of that website. I am wondering how can I do this for my agency. I have white labelled the hosting and want to show my brand.

Comment: Most of those sites rely on ASN data. So you would have to get an ASN and/or CBLOCK of ips from official sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information provided by many of these "who is hosting this" type websites is obtained by them looking up who is the netblock owner of the IP address that is hosting the website.

There is no way to change this information unless you are the actual owner of the IP space. ARIN does have a Customer record class where the real owner of the IP space can specify the customer who is currently using the IP space but from my experience not many hosts will set this for you. Even if the Customer record class is being used the real netblock owner will still be included.

While it won't change the netblock owner you can ask your host if they will allow you to change the RDNS of the IP address to display your company/brand URL.